# Div does not expand with more text. It expands with image. Tried both clear and overflow

Tags: html, css

I have some pages on my website.  They're all almost identical to each other.  Only the topics are different.

I have a 'contact us' page with a google maps link at the bottom...it works great.  I also have an 'about us' page.  But that's the issue...I have quite a bit of text...but the div is not expanding with the text.  As a result about a third of the text is not visible.  I know this is a fairly common issue and I'm aware of solutions on here.  However they don't seem to work.   I don't want the default width and height to change.
 Tried

```
 clear: both;
```

and

```
.clear{width: 100%; clear: both; height: 0px; line-height:0px;}
```

it's quite odd considering it expands in the 'contact us' page and it doesn't in the 'about us page'

This is the div element on style.css

```
.div-wrapper{

    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: relative;
   display:table;
}
```

This is about us.html

```
<section class="div-wrapper">

ABOUT US
<br>
<p class="home">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque porttitor egestas nulla, sed vestibulum nisl fringilla sed. Donec auctor a neque ac sollicitudin. Nam non sapien aliquet, molestie eros ornare, imperdiet est. Maecenas consectetur magna at arcu accumsan, sit amet dictum leo feugiat. Vivamus sit amet imperdiet erat. Fusce ullamcorper neque et metus fringilla lobortis. Nulla vulputate tristique est, nec tincidunt magna posuere sed. Cras vestibulum turpis et urna porta tempor eget in ex. Mauris elementum, metus ut mollis dapibus, nisl dui viverra odio, vel vehicula augue lacus vel sapien. In libero massa, feugiat vel risus vel, lobortis fermentum quam. Nulla a elit non risus semper semper. Mauris ullamcorper, ex at aliquam dignissim, nisi velit faucibus orci, eu suscipit dolor ante elementum magna. Fusce lacinia, neque vel scelerisque tempus, nunc neque blandit nisi, a faucibus odio dui gravida tortor. Nullam porttitor, massa vel scelerisque ornare, libero lorem vestibulum felis, quis vulputate nulla turpis eget magna. Aenean a eros purus.




                   <br>

</p>

<div class='clear'></div>
</section>
```

Thank you.

Comment: expands just fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/1ohkdx4b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your width and height to be `min-width:70%;` and `min-height:70%;`

```css
.div-wrapper{

    min-width: 70%;
    min-height: 70%;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: relative;
   display:table;
}
```

```html
<section class="div-wrapper">

ABOUT US
<br>
<p class="home">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque porttitor egestas nulla, sed vestibulum nisl fringilla sed. Donec auctor a neque ac sollicitudin. Nam non sapien aliquet, molestie eros ornare, imperdiet est. Maecenas consectetur magna at arcu accumsan, sit amet dictum leo feugiat. Vivamus sit amet imperdiet erat. Fusce ullamcorper neque et metus fringilla lobortis. Nulla vulputate tristique est, nec tincidunt magna posuere sed. Cras vestibulum turpis et urna porta tempor eget in ex. Mauris elementum, metus ut mollis dapibus, nisl dui viverra odio, vel vehicula augue lacus vel sapien. In libero massa, feugiat vel risus vel, lobortis fermentum quam. Nulla a elit non risus semper semper. Mauris ullamcorper, ex at aliquam dignissim, nisi velit faucibus orci, eu suscipit dolor ante elementum magna. Fusce lacinia, neque vel scelerisque tempus, nunc neque blandit nisi, a faucibus odio dui gravida tortor. Nullam porttitor, massa vel scelerisque ornare, libero lorem vestibulum felis, quis vulputate nulla turpis eget magna. Aenean a eros purus.




                   <br>

</p>

<div class='clear'></div>
</section>
```

min and max allow you to override the default width of the element. Max can be used to set the maximum width where it will not go any further than the specified width.

The default width is 100%.

Try removing most of the text to be a one-liner and set the min-width to 20%. You will see that the div is a much smaller width now.